# Meaning and origin of 「退がる」

Tags: meaning, words, etymology

I was reading a manga and a character said:

> 今宵はここまでだ
>   下がって良いぞ

After they noticed that the person they were talking to didn't move, they said:

> おい
>   余は退がれと
>   言ったのだ

That's why I'm guessing 退がる reads and means the same as 下{さ}がる, but I don't understand how it came to be. It's hard to find something about it on the internet.

退{しさ}る comes up. It seems to have the same meaning as 下{さ}がる in this context, as well as the more modern word 退{しりぞ}く.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Reading / Spelling

As you noticed, 退がる is not a normal collocation of kanji and okurigana.

Referring to my copy of Shogakukan's *Kokugo Dai Jiten* (online version [here](https://kotobank.jp/word/%E9%80%80-556241#E7.B2.BE.E9.81.B8.E7.89.88.20.E6.97.A5.E6.9C.AC.E5.9B.BD.E8.AA.9E.E5.A4.A7.E8.BE.9E.E5.85.B8)), 退 has the following recognized *kun'yomi*:

- 退る【しさる】
- 退く【しぞく】
- 退く【しりぞく】
- 退ける【しりぞける】
- 退る【すさる】
- 退く【そく】
- 退く【どく】
- 退かす【どかす】
- 退ける【どける】
- 退く【のく】
- 退かす【のかす】
- 退ける【のける】
- 退く【ひく】
- 退ける【ひける】

Despite the impressive number of potential readings, none of them end in ～がる, nor even ～ぐ.

#### Origins

As you guessed from the context, this appears to be author's license in choosing a non-standard spelling for the verb 下【さ】がる ("to draw back, to leave").  A common synonym for this is indeed 退【しりぞ】く.  This kind of cross-use, where the author uses a reading from one word and the spelling from another, is very common in manga.  Usually, you'll get furigana to help with the reading, but sometimes those will be omitted.

Comment: "This kind of cross-use, where the author uses a reading from one word and the spelling from another is very common in manga" Indeed, I have seen that before, but never like this. Here, the author is simply substituting the kanji --- not even changing the okurigana --- and leaving the actual meaning and reading of the word the same. So it even seems hard for me to say that the spelling comes from a word and the reading comes from another, because 退がる isn't even really a word. I generally see that use like [this](https://pbs.twimg.com/media/CBU5r_VU8AArP9B?format=png&name=medium).

Comment: It's not that it "isn't even really a word".  The word isn't what's written, it's what's spoken, and the writing *does* represent an actual word; it's merely that it's a non-standard way of writing that word down.

Comment: How do I know it's okay to substitute kanjis while maintaining the reading, though? Like, could I write 工{つく}る, for example? I wonder, if さがる started to be written more frequently as 退がる, would that reading eventually be added to 退's kun'yomi list?

Comment: @E.Matsunaga In this case, I'm rather surprised that it's not listed on dictionaries considering its widespread use. If you search it on google.co.jp, you'll find tons of examples including novels.